# JavaFX Button not centered after changing the Style-Class

Tags: css, javafx

The Application looks something like this before a button is clicked:
[image: Initial View]

However when I click one of the buttons, the Button is 'highlighted' by changing its style-class. Then this happens:
[image]
As you can see, the button is no longer centered.

When creating the Buttons, I set these values to ensure their initial scaling:

```
b.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
b.setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

And to highlight the Button:

```
public static void highlightButton(Button b){
    if(!(b.getParent() instanceof VBox)) return;

    VBox v = (VBox) b.getParent();

    ObservableList<Node> o = v.getChildren();
    Button tmp;
    for(Node n : o){
        if(n instanceof Button){
            tmp = (Button) n;
            tmp.getStyleClass().removeAll("selected-button");
            tmp.getStyleClass().add("button");
        }
    }

    b.getStyleClass().removeAll("button");
    b.getStyleClass().add("selected-button");
}
```

And the CSS formatting:

```
.selected-button{
    -fx-padding: 5 22 5 22;

    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent transparent -fx-border;
    -fx-border-width: 2;

    -fx-background-color: transparent;

    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-base-2;
}

.button {
    -fx-padding: 5 22 5 22;

    -fx-border-color: -fx-border;
    -fx-border-width: 2;

    -fx-background-color: transparent;

    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-base-2;
}
```

Thank you for any help you might provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
public static void highlightButton(final Button b) {
    if (!(b.getParent() instanceof VBox)) {
        return;
    }

    final VBox v = (VBox) b.getParent();

    final ObservableList<Node> o = v.getChildren();
    Button tmp;
    for (final Node n : o) {
        if (n instanceof Button) {
            tmp = (Button) n;
            tmp.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected"), false);
        }
    }
    b.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected"), true);
}
```

And the CSS formatting:

```
.button {
-fx-padding: 5 22 5 22;
-fx-border-color: -fx-border;
-fx-border-width: 2;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-font-family: "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
-fx-font-size: 12pt;
-fx-text-fill: -fx-base-2k;
 }
.button:selected {
   -fx-border-color: transparent transparent transparent -fx-border;
 }
```

Comment: Indeed! it seems like the problem was me removing the .button class.